# Dynamically duplicate columns in an R dataframe using column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 5 columns, Units1, Units2, Units3, Units4, Units5. I am trying to create a new column say

```
master$Sales <- master$Units1
```

However, I want this Units1 to be dynamic such that Sales has the datatype of UnitsX.

My current solution created Sales as a list instead of double.

```
Sales_Variable <- "Units"
UnitsType <- x #which is 1 in this case
master$Sales <- master[names(master) == paste0(Sales_Variable,UnitsType)]
```

Please guide me on how I can solve this.

Thanks,

Ashutosh Deshpande

Comment: It sounds like you want _one_ column `Sales` to have the values of _five_ columns `Units1:Units5`; can you confirm that and expand on why you think that's necessary?

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY I am running various Iterations of a model, and each time I have to take a different column (there are 8 such columns), but keep the entire other code intact, thus Sales is a fixed column.

Comment: `master$Sales <- master[[ paste0(Sales_Variable, UnitsType) ]]`?

Comment: If you're running different models/regression, you can also consider _not_ creating `Sales` each time, instead updating your formula such that `Units1` is removed from the RHS and replaces the previous LHS.

Comment: Actually yes, i was doing this inside a for loop. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.